# Entity Framework 6 Where in Bulk Update/Delete in one transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In EF6, I want to update/delete bulk data in one query.
My code is

```
 using (var context = _dataContextFactory.GetContext())
            {
                var result1 = from b in context.MyTables
                    where new List<int> {592, 593, 594}.Contains(b.Id)
                    select b;


                foreach (var item in result1 )
                {
                    item.StatusId = 3;
                }

                context.SaveChanges();

            }
```

But in Sql Profiler, there are three scripts

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [StatusId] = @0 WHERE ([Id] = @1) ',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=592
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [StatusId] = @0 WHERE ([Id] = @1) ',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=593
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [StatusId] = @0 WHERE ([Id] = @1) ',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=594
```

is it possible to get script with Where In clause in one query?

Comment: You're mistaking "transaction" and "query". If you want to perform a bulk update based on a dynamic where-statement rather than identity, you can't use EF. It doesn't support it out of the box. There are, however, plenty of third party libraries that provide extensions to EF - including bulk updating or inserting.

Comment: you right @J.Steen! I have changed my words transaction to query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in Entity Framework out of the box. However, you can use the batch update functionality in the `EntityFramework.Extended` library:

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

There's a nuget package available, too.

An example would be:

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;

...

int[] myIds = { 592, 593, 594 };

using (var context = _dataContextFactory.GetContext())
{
    // Define a filter expression to retrieve matching items
    var filter = context.MyTables.Where(item => myIds.Contains(item.Id));
    // Update the StatusId of matched items
    context.MyTables.Update(filter, i => new Item { StatusId = 3 });

    // NB: no context.SaveChanges() required
}
```

NB: there may be a more efficient way of writing this, but I'm still playing with the library. It does compile down to a single SQL statement, however, and the library also includes batched DELETEs.

Finally, don't worry about the `new` expression. Any properties which are not referenced here will retain their original values.

Comment: EntityFramework.Extended now at https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus

Answer (score 0):

You can't update multiple rows in one single SQL call with EF.

What you could do instead is to write a stored procedure that'll do the job efficiently for you. Or use a third party lib that provides extensions to EF to do it.

Of course, it won't makes sense if the number of rows to update is really small.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code with the latest Z.EntityFramework.Plus (v5.1.16) based on [@Dave R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42841/dave-r) answer. Also, `.Where` and `.Update` can be placed in one statement:

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

...

int[] myIds = { 592, 593, 594 };

using (var context = _dataContextFactory.GetContext())
{
    context.MyTables
        .Where(item => myIds.Contains(item.Id))
        .Update(i => new Item { StatusId = 3 });
}
```