# Entity Framework equivalent of “UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1”?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, linq

I have a column recording number of clicks. I want to add 1 to it with a single DB call. In SQL, I can do it using

> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1

I am wandering is there a build in API(LINQ) in EF to do it? Otherwise I need to use

> Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync()

This is OK, but just curious is there a pure EF way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of EF? See [reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584523/entity-framework-6-where-in-bulk-update-delete-in-one-transaction), [reference 2](http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2015/01/26/performing-bulk-updates-entity-framework-6.1%2B)

Comment: @har07 I am using EF6, it seems there's no out of box method... I will read the references. Thanks!