# EF SaveChanges() very fast on localhost but very slow on remote database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a bulk of 100 entities (and their child elements) using the Entity Framework. It takes around 3 seconds inserting the bulk on a database which is on localhost, and 300 seconds when trying to insert the same bulk on a remote database, which is on the same intranet.

The connection between the remote database and the computer performing SaveChanges (localhost) is not slow.

I am guessing it could have something to do with firewalls or a configuration on the remote SQL server. How could I investigate the issue further?

This is the code:

```
    public void SaveProcessedProperties(object properties)
    {
        var propertiesToPersist = properties as List<Ejendom>;

        using (var db = new TinglysUdv_UdpakEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            try
            {
                foreach (var property in propertiesToPersist)
                {
                    #region Haeftelse
                    if (property.Haeftelse.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var liability in property.Haeftelse)
                        {
                            if (liability.AttachDocument)
                            {
                                var existingDoc = db.Dokument.Find(liability.DokumentIdentifikator, liability.DokumentRevisionNummer);

                                if (existingDoc == null)
                                {
                                    Dokument dbDoc;
                                    if (DocumentExists(db, liability.DokumentIdentifikator, liability.DokumentRevisionNummer, out dbDoc))
                                    {
                                        existingDoc = dbDoc;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (existingDoc != null)
                                {
                                    liability.Dokument = existingDoc;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var dok = new Dokument()
                                    {
                                        DokumentIdentifikator = liability.DokumentIdentifikator,
                                        DokumentRevisionNummer = liability.DokumentRevisionNummer
                                    };
                                    db.Dokument.Attach(dok);
                                    liability.Dokument = dok;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Adkomst
                    if (property.Adkomst.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var claim in property.Adkomst)
                        {
                            if (claim.AttachDocument)
                            {
                                var existingDoc = db.Dokument.Find(claim.DokumentIdentifikator, claim.DokumentRevisionNummer);

                                if (existingDoc == null)
                                {
                                    Dokument dbDoc;
                                    if (DocumentExists(db, claim.DokumentIdentifikator, claim.DokumentRevisionNummer, out dbDoc))
                                    {
                                        existingDoc = dbDoc;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (existingDoc != null)
                                {
                                    claim.Dokument = existingDoc;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var dok = new Dokument()
                                    {
                                        DokumentIdentifikator = claim.DokumentIdentifikator,
                                        DokumentRevisionNummer = claim.DokumentRevisionNummer
                                    };
                                    db.Dokument.Attach(dok);
                                    claim.Dokument = dok;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Servitut
                    if (property.Servitut.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var easement in property.Servitut)
                        {
                            if (easement.AttachDocument)
                            {
                                var existingDoc = db.Dokument.Find(easement.DokumentIdentifikator, easement.DokumentRevisionNummer);

                                if (existingDoc == null)
                                {
                                    Dokument dbDoc;
                                    if (DocumentExists(db, easement.DokumentIdentifikator, easement.DokumentRevisionNummer, out dbDoc))
                                    {
                                        existingDoc = dbDoc;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (existingDoc != null)
                                {
                                    easement.Dokument = existingDoc;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var dok = new Dokument()
                                    {
                                        DokumentIdentifikator = easement.DokumentIdentifikator,
                                        DokumentRevisionNummer = easement.DokumentRevisionNummer
                                    };
                                    db.Dokument.Attach(dok);
                                    easement.Dokument = dok;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                    db.Ejendom.Add(property);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

private bool DocumentExists(TinglysUdv_UdpakEntities db, Guid documentIdentifier, int documentRevision, out Dokument dbDocument)
{
    var documentExists = false;

    dbDocument = db.Dokument.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DokumentIdentifikator == documentIdentifier && x.DokumentRevisionNummer == documentRevision);

    if (dbDocument != null)
    {
        documentExists = true;
    }

    return documentExists;
}
```

Got a trail edition of [Entity Framework Profiler](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) and profiled the code. Here is the result:

[image]

For the particular context I got the following alerts:

Example of a N+1 query that EF is making:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Respekt]
       ([RettighedIdentifikator],
        [RespektServitutDato],
        [Resp_Haeft_Fremtid_id])
VALUES ('1425fd57-042a-4649-a344-0f386b59e400' /* @0 - [RettighedIdentifikator] */,
        NULL,
        NULL)

--//////////////////////////////////////////////////

SELECT [Respekt_id]
FROM   [dbo].[Respekt]
WHERE  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       AND [Respekt_id] = scope_identity()
```

Is there anything I can do about this, other than reduce the amount of entities I am trying to save?

Comment: Can you show the code your using? It could be the insert is doing it one at a time and not a buck which would cause more overhead over a network.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code

Comment: Thanks, looks like your doing the save out side the loop so my idea is not valid (I had a similar problem but my save was in the loop). Good luck with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get close to where the issue is I would run the SQL that EF generates from SQL Management Studio. After that you can run the SQL profiler, if needed.

Your code can be slow because:

1. One big SQL that is slow
2. EF generates many separate SQL statements and each of them is a bit slow. <- that's my guess

BTW. 29ms ping on Intranet is very slow. I get less than that when pinging leading search providers and 5ms when pinging www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry, I was connected to the intranet through VPN from my home computer, not from the office, my bad. The SaveChanges speed is still very slow when I run it from the office though, so problem still remains. Removed the ping and tracert stuff. Will look into profiling EF and get back. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is making a lot of database calls in all the loops through the line:

`var existingDoc = db.Dokument.Find(liability.DokumentIdentifikator, liability.DokumentRevisionNummer);`
 is issued in the  foreach loop, you need to minimze these calls.

you can do that by retrieving all the objects in one call instead of having it inside the loop

ex: instead of

```
foreach (var liability in property.Haeftelse)
                        {
                            if (liability.AttachDocument)
                            {
                                var existingDoc = db.Dokument.Find(liability.DokumentIdentifikator, liability.DokumentRevisionNummer);
}
```

You can:

```
var allLiabilities = db.Dokument.Where(a=> property.Haeftelse.Contains(a)) //you can adjust the condition exactly, ex: check on if AttachDocument = true
```

You should apply this to all other loops

This way, you will have one query for each loop.

For the SaveChanges, I believe it will issue a separate insert or update statement for each record, check the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584523/entity-framework-6-where-in-bulk-update-delete-in-one-transaction) to know how to update in bulk

Another approach is to create a stored procedure, pass the list of records as a user defined table type and do all these checks on SQL